# Javascript execute function (countdown) again

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run my code (a countdown) again, after having it already ran a couple of times.

Javascript:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
function timer() {
  var countdown = 1 * 60 * 1000;
  var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    countdown -= 1000;
    var min = Math.floor(countdown / (60 * 1000));
    var sec = Math.floor((countdown - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);

    if (countdown <= -1) {
      //alert("30 min!");
      $(".countTime").html('<div class="countTime"><input type="button" id="btn1" value="Press me!"/></div>');
      clearInterval(timerId);
      //doSomething();
    } else {
      if(min > 0) {
        $(".countTime").html(min + " : " + sec);
      } else {
        $(".countTime").html(sec);
      }
    }

  }, 1000); //1000ms. = 1sec.
}
btn1.onclick = timer;
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countTime">
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Press me!"/>
</div>
```

It only runs for one time. Pressing the button and running the countdown a second time doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

problem is;

```
btn1.onclick = timer;
```

you have to bind click like this;

```
$(document).on("click", btn1, function(){
 timer();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a9txuLhd/

Comment: Or even better, `$(document).on('click', '#btn1', function () {...`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the html removes the click handler, so you need to set it again after changing the html back to the button.

You can do this with `$("#btn1").click(timer);`

So the code will become

```
    ...
if (countdown <= -1) {
    //alert("30 min!");
    $(".countTime").html('<div class="countTime"><input type="button" id="btn1" value="Press me!"/></div>');
    $("#btn1").click(timer); // <-- rebinding click handler
    clearInterval(timerId);
    //doSomething();
} else {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Added onclick event in the countdown <= -1 condition. Hope this helps.

```
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
 var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');

 function timer(){
   console.log("yo in method")
   var countdown = 1 * 6 * 1000;
   var timerId = setInterval(function(){
   countdown -= 1000;
   var min = Math.floor(countdown / (60 * 1000));
   var sec = Math.floor((countdown - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);

   if (countdown <= -1) {
        //alert("30 min!");
        $(".countTime").html('<div class="countTime"><input type="button" 
        id="btn1" value="Press me!"/></div>');
        $("#btn1").click(timer);
        clearInterval(timerId);
        //doSomething();
 } 
 else {
     if(min > 0){
         $(".countTime").html(min + " : " + sec);
 }
 else {
        $(".countTime").html(sec);
 }
}

 }, 1000); //1000ms. = 1sec.
}


</script>
<div class="countTime">
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Press me!" onClick="timer()"/>
</div>
```